# ORDER BY DATE in sql Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT *  
FROM stock   
ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, date_sold, 103);
```

I've used the above query to show my stock according to date, but I receive the following error:

```
ORA-00904: "DATE_SOLD": invalid identifier  
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Can anybody help me solve this problem?

Comment: If `DATE_SOLD` is an invalid identifier, then it is not a column in your table.  You can't do this.  Perhaps you should delete this question and ask another with sample data and desired results.

Comment: `CONVERT(datetime, date_sold, 103)` is an SQL server expression to convert a string from `dd/mm/yyyy` format to a `DATETIME` data type. In Oracle you need to use `TO_DATE( date_sold, 'dd/mm/yyyy' )`.

Comment: If your column is a `date` then just use `order by date_column` no need to convert it back and forth

Answer (score 2):

You are misusing the Oracle CONVERT function. You can check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620) for details on how it works.

If you want to show your stock according to date (I suppose you mean sort by date), you don't need convert at all. Just use **order by date_sold**.

```
SELECT *  
FROM stock   
ORDER BY date_sold;
```